# “Seeing something in first person” in German

Tags: expression

My girlfriend was curious how we celebrate Christmas in my homeland, so I was about to write her

> Wait until you come with me, and you will see it in first person.

But then I thought:

- Is it really possible to translate that literally?
- Can I write this?

> Du kannst es sehen in erste Person.

**UPDATE** I changed the context of the question, because it was causing confusion about the point of my question. :)

Comment: ... dann wirst Du es selbst sehen.

Comment: Please do not change your question in such a radical way. The situation you are describing now is crucially different from the one before and thus invalidating existing answers and making formerly incorrect answers correct. This causes confusion. Your initial question was perfectly valid, but only a little bit difficult to answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Du kannst es sehen in erste Person.

is not a correct sentence.

It’s actually hard to translate without using the phrase *mit eigenen Augen sehen,* which would kind of imply her being there in person, instead of seeing pictures taken from your perspective.

Comment: I have changed the context of the question, because it was causing confusion about the point of the question. Now there is no pictures :)

Comment: @Dbugger the German expression *"mit eigenen Augen sehen"* is also used figuratively -it is probably the closest you can get for "to see in first Person".

Answer (score 3):

"Mit eigenen Augen sehen" oder "selbst sehen" sind die deutschen Begriffe für "see for yourself".

Comment: Sure, but that is not exactly my question.

Comment: Aber hier geht es ja darum, dass die Freundin es eben nicht mit eigenen Augen sieht, sondern eben nur über Bilder, die aus der Ego-Perspektive aufgenommen wurden.

Comment: Do not complicate yourself too much. I am just asking if that expression is correct or understandable

Comment: @Dbugger If that is really your question, the answer is simply: no

Answer (score 0):

Your suggestion does not work at all and I'm not even sure if I would understand what you're trying to say. The most generic option would be using "selbst". However, it is highly dependent on context. Sometimes, the "selbst" might be out of place because, after all, all we see is for ourselves.

> Dann wirst du es (selbst) sehen.
>   Dann wirst du es mit eigenen Augen sehen.
>   Dann wirst du es "life" sehen.

In the context currently provided "sehen" is not a good choice. "Erleben" is much more fitting.

> Dann wirst du es (selbst) erleben